# Alfsen Shultz theorem-the space of states of $C^*$-algebra depends only on Jordan structure

Tags: rt.representation-theory, c-star-algebras, quantum-mechanics, jordan-algebras

According to the [article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Alfsen-Shultz+theorem) on nLab the Alfsen Shultz theorem states that the space of states of a given $C^*$-algebra depends on somehow weaker structure namely on the so called *Jordan algebra* structure. This article gives reference for this theorem: however I've checked the [cited paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/256105444_A_Gelfand-Naimark_Theorem_for_Jordan_Algebras) and I don;t see how the main theorem (namely theorem 9.5 in this paper) implies the above statement. For convienience I quote this theorem below: Let $A$ be a JB algebra (see the Introduction of the paper). Then there is unique Jordan ideal $J$ such that $A/J$ has faithful, isometric Jordan representation as an JC algebra and every factor representation of $A$ not anihilating $J$ is onto the exceptional algebra $M_3^8$ .

Comment: The fact that you can get back the Jordan multiplication follows because you can recover the squaring map because the state space of a unital C$^*$-algebra is *strongly spectral*, a notion defined [here](https://www.ams.org/books/memo/0172), although perhaps the place to look is the two books by Alfsen and Shultz called *State Spaces of Operator Algebras* and *Geometry of State Spaces of Operator Algebras*.

Comment: This would give the one direction: that the state space is enough to recover the Jordan product, right? How about the converse implication?

Comment: Wait -- isn't the fact that the state space depends only on the Jordan structure pretty much trivial? A state is a positive linear functional, and "positive" and "linear" depend only on the Jordan structure. It's the other direction -- recovering the Jordan algebra from the state space -- which is hard.

Comment: @truebaran An element $x$ of a Jordan algebra is positive iff it is a square, *i.e.* there is a $y$ such that $x = y \circ y$. (This agrees with the fact that positive elements of C$^*$-algebras are the squares of self-adjoint elements.) The positive cone and unit allow you to define when a linear functional is a state, and get the state space.

Comment: Thank you, you are both right